# Python While в while

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему не срабатывает второй while. Почему-то ask не может менять значение two и поэтому петля получается бесконечной.

```
one=0
while one!=1:     
    speed=3*10**8# скорость света    
    frequency=input("Введите номер канала wi-fi или введите 0, чтобы указать частоту вручную\n ")# частота канала
    if frequency=='1':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2412*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='2':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2417*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='3':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2422*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='4':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2427*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='5':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2432*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='6':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2437*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='7':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2442*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='8':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2447*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='9':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2452*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='10':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2457*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='11':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2462*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='12':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2467*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='13':
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(2472*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
    elif frequency=='0':        
        two=0        
        while two!=1:
            frequency2=int(input("Введите частоту в мегагерцах\n "))# частота
            print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", (speed/(frequency2*1000)/4)*1.01, "сантиметров")
            ask=input("Запустить заново? Y/N\n ")
            if ask=="Y" or "y":
                two +=0
            elif ask=="N" or "n":
                two +=1                
    else:
        print("Неверный номер канала. Укажите канал от 1 до 13\n ")

    question=input("Нажмите 1, чтобы произвести другой расчёт или 0, чтобы выйти\n ")
    if question=='1':
        one +=0
    elif question=='0':
        one +=1
    else:
        one +=1
```

Учёл советы и переделал. Всем спасибо

```
    one=0
while one!=1:    
    speed=3*10**8# скорость света    
    frequency=int(input("Укажите номер канала wi-fi или введите 0, чтобы указать частоту вручную\n "))# частота канала
    if frequency in range(1,13):# диапазон каналов
        formula=(speed/((2407 + frequency*5)*1000*10))# формула длины волны для каналов wi-fi в сантиметрах
        print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", round(formula/4*1.01,2), "сантиметров")
        print("Размер сторон рефлектора ", round(formula*1.01,2),"сантиметров")
        print("Расстояние вибратор-рефлектор ", round(formula/8.7,2),"сантиметров")
    elif frequency==0:        
        two=0        
        while two!=1:
            frequency2=float(input("Укажите частоту в мегагерцах\n "))# произвольная частота
            formula2=(speed/(frequency2*1000*10))# формула длины волны для произвольной частоты в сантиметрах
            print("Внешняя сторона квадрата антенны равна ", round(formula2/4*1.01,2), "сантиметров")
            print("Размер сторон рефлектора ", round(formula2*1.01,2), "сантиметров")
            print("Расстояние вибратор-рефлектор ", round(formula2/8.7*1.01,2), "сантиметров")
            ask=input("Указать другую частоту? Y/N\n ")
            if ask.upper()=="N":# .upper() - игнорирование регистра буквы
                two +=1
                #break# прерывание цикла командой break               
    else:
        print("Неверный номер канала. Укажите канал от 1 до 13\n ")        
    question=input("Начать новый расчёт? Y/N\n ")
    if question in ('N', 'n'):# любой вариант ответа из перечисленных
        one +=1
```

Comment: Используйте формулу `(speed/((2407 + freq*5)*1000)/4)*1.01` вместо этого страшилища...

Comment: а в чем смысл `two +=0`? :)

Comment: Я вообще к программированию имею примерное никакое отношение, последний раз в школе много лет назад было пара уроков по паскалю. two +=0 для того, чтобы петля не разрывалась, при этом был вопрос и ответ.

Comment: ``if ask=="Y" or "y"`` и ``elif ask=="N" or "n"`` делают совсем не то, что вам кажется!

Comment: У вас к продолжению расчета приведет ввод любого символа или даже просто Enter без ввода. В целом, это не плохо, просто советую изменить логику так, чтобы any_key приводил к наиболее вероятному исходу. Если скорее ожидается выход, чем расчет следующего значения, логику надо инвертировать. И да, унифицируйте проверку, либо `or`, либо `in`. так же советую переделать выход на `break`. Будет проще понять код через месяц :)

Comment: Переделал, хотя так и не понял пока, как не писать формулу каждый раз. :) any_key оставлю для продолжения, а n для выхода. С break пока не разобрался хорошо. Вряд ли через месяц мне понадобится здесь что-то менять. Довольно бесполезная программа. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас ошибка в условиях:

```
if ask=="Y" or "y":
    two +=0
elif ask=="N" or "n":
    two +=1
```

Дело в том, что тут у вас на самом деле два условия – `ask=="Y"` и `bool("y")`. А т.к. `bool('y')` всегда будет `True`, потому что булевая проверка строки это проверка что она не пустая, и используется оператор `or`, то проверка на самом будет `if ask=="Y" or True:`, что при любых значениях `ask` вернет `True`.

---

Правильно будет:

```
if ask == "Y" or ask == "y":
    two += 0
elif ask == "N" or ask == "n":
    two += 1
```

Или более близкий вариант к логике из вопроса:

```
# Альтернативный вариант с строкой:
# if ask in "Yy":
if ask in ("Y", "y"):
    two += 0
elif ask in ("N", "n"):
    two += 1
```

Либо, привести сам `ask` к тому же регистру, что и проверяемые значения:

```
ask = ask.upper()

if ask == "Y":
    two += 0
elif ask == "N":
    two += 1
```

---

**PS.**

А так, достаточно было одного `if`'а:

```
if ask.upper() == "N":
    two += 1
```

Comment: Спасибо. Учёл все советы и переписал

Comment: @Нуби, если мой ответ вам помог, примите его. Нажмите на галочку у ответа :)